# Yii creating a url loop resulting in too many redirects

Tags: php, yii

I am in a weird problem.. while my Yii 1.1 application works fine on localhost,

it creates a weird url redirect loop on remote server like this

https://cart.example.com/cn/osadmin/index.php/product/cart.example.com/cn//cn/osadmin/index.php/product/cart.example.com/cn//cn/....................

Kindly note that the application is in the `cn` folder : `https://cart.example.com/cn/`

Here are some configuration settings that might be help to find out the root of the problem..

```
'config'=>array(
                'site_url'=>'https://cart.example.com/cn',
                'document_root'=>$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'cn/osadmin/',
                'upload_path'=>'uploads/', 
                'product_version'=>'',
                'template_path'=>'',
                'ssl'=>'https',
            ),
```

Anyone having experienced such scenario before? any clue what could be the possible reasons behind such a behaviour ?

One more strange thing.. the loop is created only when I access the controller action `product/create`. when I access other actions in same controller, they work fine.

I tried to remove all the code from this specific controller/action and then tried to access .. but the same problem.

Comment: Yii1   or Yii2  ?  please explain

Comment: Yii1 sir.. :) You have always helped me.. please help this time.. too I really need to sove this..

Comment: show your url call  .. code please

Comment: I think I can share with you personally somewhere.. not publicly

Comment: you have problem  to show the code that build the url ???? i don't understand ..

Comment: I mean I can share the whole github repo with you .. 45 mb. If you can kindly duplicate the same on your localhost, you can see what's going on ... or should I share just the controller action code here ? ..

Comment: not all the code  ... just the code for build the url  ... the url call

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sEeRSWTJ